# Setting KDE to crop the laptop's screen to match external VGA device's ratio

Tags: xorg, kde, monitors, display-settings, resolution

I have a laptop with 16:9 screen ration. Sometimes I need to attach it to a projector via VGA. The projector ratio is 4:3.

I use `System Settings`->`Hardware`->`Display and Monitor`->`Size & Orientation` to enable the VGA connection and set it's resolution. The problem is that all the resolutions for the VGA are 4:3, while the resolution for the laptop's screen is 1600x900(which is 16:9). That means that whatever resolution I pick, either the image on the projector is cut, the image on the local screen is cut, or both.

Is there a way to force crop the local screen to 4:3? Ofcourse, I want the sides of the screens to be blank, not the to crop the image itself.