# output cut on the projector because laptop resolution is 16:9 and projector is lower

Tags: x11, xorg, multi-monitor

My query is same/similar to [Setting KDE to crop the laptop's screen to match external VGA device's ratio](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68339/setting-kde-to-crop-the-laptops-screen-to-match-external-vga-devices-ratio)

In my case my screen resolution is 1366 x 768 which is non-standard but still resolves to 16:9 whereas most old projectors have 4:3 with the result that the picture is cut. In such a case is something else feasible?

I did see [Viewing a part of the screen in a window on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97005/viewing-a-part-of-the-screen-in-a-window-on-linux/97487#97487) which seems promising. I have not understood though the `--pos 100x100` code which has been shared therein.

Here's the output of my display via xrandr

```
$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1366x768      60.00*+
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   640x480       59.94  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Also here's my X version

```
$ X -version

X.Org X Server 1.17.2
Release Date: 2015-06-16
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.1.0 x86_64 Debian
Current Operating System: Linux think-debian 4.2.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.2.1-2 (2015-09-27) x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-1-amd64 root=UUID=aaafd0a1-62db-4216-80be-cf0dc016ac7c ro initrd=/install/initrd.gz ipv6.disable=1 init=/lib/systemd/systemd
Build Date: 11 August 2015  10:51:15AM
xorg-server 2:1.17.2-1.1 (http://www.debian.org/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.33.2
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
```

As can be seen xorg is latest and similar is the case with xrandr. Have 8 GB of RAM so that should be enough for whatever is required herein.

Comment: Please edit question to explain how your projector is connected to your laptop (VGA? HDMI? DP?), and if `xrandr` gives any extra information when your projector is connected.